# How can I change the fixed height of my Image in Gatsby for mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm currently mapping through an array of images in my Gatsby site, where each image has a fixed height of 395px and auto width. However, I need to be able to change the fixed height of the images to 200px for screen sizes below 768px.

I've tried to do this with two separate image components, rendering them with a windowSize conditional, however this doesn't really work.

How can I achieve the above? Below is my image component for the fixed height of 395px.

ScrollImage.tsx

```
const ScrollImage = ({ src, ...rest }) => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      images: allFile(
        filter: { internal: { mediaType: { regex: "/image/" } } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            relativePath
            extension
            publicURL
            childImageSharp {
              fixed(height: 395) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  const match = useMemo(
    () => data.images.edges.find(({ node }) => src === node.relativePath),
    [data, src]
  );

  if (!match) return null;

  const { node: { childImageSharp, publicURL, extension } = {} } = match;

  if (extension === "svg" || !childImageSharp) {
    return <img src={publicURL} {...rest} />;
  }

  return (
    <Img
      fixed={childImageSharp.fixed}
      imgStyle={{ WebkitUserDrag: "none" }}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
};

export default ScrollImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [art-directing](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/#art-directing-multiple-images) approach to show different images at different breakpoints. To do this you can define your own array of fixed or fluid images, along with a media key per image, and pass it to `gatsby-image`’s fixed or fluid `props`. The media key that is set on an image can be any valid CSS media query.

Here's an example:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => {
  // Set up the array of image data and `media` keys.
  // You can have as many entries as you'd like.
  const sources = [
    data.mobileImage.childImageSharp.fluid,
    {
      ...data.desktopImage.childImageSharp.fluid,
      media: `(min-width: 768px)`,
    },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello art-directed gatsby-image</h1>
      <Img fluid={sources} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    mobileImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "blog/avatars/kyle-mathews.jpeg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1000, quality: 100) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    desktopImage: file(
      relativePath: { eq: "blog/avatars/kyle-mathews-desktop.jpeg" }
    ) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 2000, quality: 100) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```